# Segmentation faut on PyErr_SetString

Tags: python, api

I am trying to implement a proper error handling for my python-ctype-exported functions. If I understand correctly, I should call PyErr_SetString() and than return NULL. But the call to PyErr_SetString() segfaults. What do I miss?

C code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "Python.h"
PyObject *test_error(int x)
{
    assert(0==NULL);
    printf("x=%d\n",x);
    switch(x)
    {
        case  0:  Py_RETURN_NONE; // works
        case  1:  return PyString_FromString("Hello, World!"); // works
        case  2:  return PyInt_FromLong(123); // works
        case  3:  return PyFloat_FromDouble(123.4); // works
        default:
            printf("Setting error message.\n");
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"This is my error!"); // segfault!
            printf("return\n"); // never reach this line
            return 0;
    }
    assert(0);
}
```

Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libe.so')

def test_error(x):
    lib.test_error.restype  = py_object
    lib.test_error.argtypes = [c_int]
    return lib.test_error(x)    

for i in [0,1,2,3,4]:
    try:
        print('test_error(%d)' % i)
        print test_error(i)
        print
    except:
        print 'error!'
```

Compilation (checked on Linux[raspberry pi with gcc-4.6, gcc-4.8] and Mac[core2duo notebook, gcc-5.1.0], Linux-amd-ubuntu[gcc.5.1 and with an extra linker option -fPIC]):
    gcc `python2.7-config  --includes --libs --ldflags` -shared -o libe.so e.c

Run:

```
$ python e.py
test_error(0)
x=0
None

test_error(1)
x=1
Hello, World!

test_error(2)
x=2
123

test_error(3)
x=3
123.4

test_error(4)
x=4
Setting error message.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

valgrind errors on a Linux AMD node:

```
test_error(4)
x=4
Setting error message.
==4839== Invalid read of size 8
==4839==    at 0x518A8D: PyErr_SetString (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x6833A09: test_error (in /home/zvyagin/Projects/learning/python/c-api/libe.so)
==4839==    by 0x6630ADB: ffi_call_unix64 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1)
==4839==    by 0x663040B: ffi_call (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1)
==4839==    by 0x641E5FD: _ctypes_callproc (in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
==4839==    by 0x641FF9D: ??? (in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
==4839==    by 0x52CC1F: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x52CF31: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x55C593: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x5B7391: PyEval_EvalCode (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x469662: ??? (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x4699E2: PyRun_FileExFlags (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==  Address 0x48 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4839== 
==4839== 
==4839== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4839==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x48
==4839==    at 0x518A8D: PyErr_SetString (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x6833A09: test_error (in /home/zvyagin/Projects/learning/python/c-api/libe.so)
==4839==    by 0x6630ADB: ffi_call_unix64 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1)
==4839==    by 0x663040B: ffi_call (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1)
==4839==    by 0x641E5FD: _ctypes_callproc (in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
==4839==    by 0x641FF9D: ??? (in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
==4839==    by 0x52CC1F: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x52CF31: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x55C593: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x5B7391: PyEval_EvalCode (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x469662: ??? (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
==4839==    by 0x4699E2: PyRun_FileExFlags (in /usr/bin/python2.7)
```

Comment: There is no problem with the code if I use distutils instead of ctypes. So probably I do not use good compiler/linker flags? I doubt there is a problem in ctypes code.